# Slack API for deleting Incoming Webhook

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have followed the process for using Slack Incoming Webhooks to post messages to channels successfully as per https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks. However, I could not find an API to delete a specific incoming Webhook. I can delete a specific webhook from the web UI if I go to the Slack App page so the API has to exist. Can someone please point me to the right API ?

Comment: I am wondering about this issue also. 
Basically, what I found out is that only the owner of the app and member of the workspace has an UI to see list of incoming Webhooks for that app and workspace combination. 

If you go to your app settings, manage distribution and distribute, you can find this message at bottom almost.


`Installation Count

This app has been installed on 0 active workspaces, and used by 0 users active within the past 28 days. (Counts are updated every 24 hours.)`

I am not sure if that gets updated with list of hooks later. I will update if it changes.